# Shoes accessing class variables and interacting with them?

Tags: ruby, shoes

What I'm making: a simple RPG.

What I want to do:
1. Users current stats are stored in a custom class, which initialise as 1 at the start of the program. 
2. User clicks "add 1" button (or selects it in a list, or clicks a checkbox etc)
3. Program retrieves current score, adds one. 
4. Program displays the number "2"

I could do it on the command line! I am fairly new to ruby (2 years of amateurish doodling) and totes new to Shoes, and struggling to make them play together.

Specific questions:
1) I've written out my classes a la Ruby. Do they go inside the Shoes.app flow or outside?
2) In my command line version, I use strength.name and strength.level to output "Strength: 6"

(Strength is an example instance of the class Skill, with methods allowing us to read the info it stores. New programmer, still finds it easier to think in the concrete rather than the abstract!)

I've tried using that in shoes and it doesn't work. I've also tried strength.name = para, which is how Shoes seems to display its own variables in the samples.

Where is my error...?

Can you not use classes like that in Shoes? Or is it to do with the instance variables thing, and the places data is in the program? (A common error of mine)  Or have I got my basic syntax wrong?

Cheers all. I've gotta say I'm totally buzzed to have finally written a program which LOOKS LIKE A PROGRAM, albeit a 90s one. Although all it does right now is open. Still, I feel like surf-master of the digital waves ^_^

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871055/my-classes-cant-use-shoes-methods-like-para where you ask something similar

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your class in the same ruby file

```
class YourClass
    # Class stuff
end

Shoes.app do 
    foo = YourClass.new(......)
    # Shoes app stuff
end
```

You can also declare it in another a file and import it using

```
require_relative 'yourfile.rb' # The relative is optional
```

Also,

```
strength.name = para
```

is obviously wrong even though I'm not really sure want you want to do. If you want to display the value of Strength.name you can use :

```
para "#{strength.name}" # if the para doesn't exist yet
# OR #
@@the_name_of_your_para.replace "#{strength.name}" # if the para exists and you want to change the content
```

I hope I helped you, if I didn't please tell me, I'll be glad to try harder!
Happy ruby coding.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I've been struggling to get some of the basic concepts down - hard to tell whether my program isn't working because I made a spelling mistake, or am trying to fit a round peg in the square hole. This is super useful, cheers